# Errors with the Apple Help Indexer

Tags: macos

A coworker is having problems generating the search for a Chinese help system in the Apple Help Indexer 4.3. The HTML pages are encoded as GB2312. When she creates the index, she gets many “NSXMLParserErrorDomain” errors and an error that the action cannot be finished.

She’s indexing the help on Mavericks 10.9.5.

Has anyone ever run across this problem?

Comment: Your files are not XHTML - you need to fix that

Comment: The files use the XHTML Transitional DTD: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Do the files verify against that DTD - i.e. the header says XHTML but are they really XHTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files to be used have to be valid XHTML files and have to verify against the XHTML DTD

From Apple's [Authoring Apple Help Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-CIHGHDFJ)

> you need to create HTML files for your help pages. To ensure that your help displays properly in Help Viewer, your help files should comply with the HTML 4.01 specification. Your main file—which contains the AppleTitle meta tag—should conform to the XHTML 1.0 specification.

As the main file is XHTML Apple uses the faster XML parser for it, which Uses Objective C classes beginning with NSXML and errors (e.g. non valid or verified text) will raise NSXMLParserErrorDomain errors.

Comment: In the past, we've generated the help index with the same invalid help pages, but I can see where the invalidity would be a problem. Could there be any other issues?